# Updating one column based on the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table named Vendor, within this table I have a column called AccountTerms which is shows only a value (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3) and so on. I also have a column that I want to use (`ulARAgeing`) in order to reflect the meaning of that value, such as:

```
0: Current
1: 30 Days
2: 60 Days
```

and so on...

What I need is a script that will look at the value in AccountTerms and will then update `ulARAgeing` to show the word value shown above. How do I do this?

Comment: just to make it clear. AccountTerms  and ulARAgeing belongs to same table? Can you please descrive your tables structure?

Comment: "update ulARAgeing" Where is the value? Another table? It will be an update at a time accomplished through a form?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am going to try to explain this in a simple manner as much as possible so it's easy to understand :

Let's assume, you have a table `Vendor` setup something like this:

```
create table Vendor (AccountTerms int, ulARAgeing varchar(50));
```

And, then we will insert some sample values for both columns in `Vendor` table:

```
insert into Vendor values
(0,'Test'),
(1,'Test1'),
(2,'Test2');
```

Next, we will write an update statement to update your `ulARAgeing` column based on the values in `AccountTerms` column in the same table:

```
update vendor 
set ulARAgeing = (CASE 
                      WHEN AccountTerms = 0 
                        THEN 'Current'
                      WHEN AccountTerms = 1
                        THEN '30 Days'
                      WHEN AccountTerms = 2
                        THEN '60 Days'
                    END);
```

`CASE WHEN` is similar to using `IF..ELSE` statement in most other programming languages. So, here we will be updating the existing `ulARAgeing` value to different string value based on the condition in the case when statement. So, for e.g. if the `AccountTerms = 0` then we will update the value for `ulARAgeing` to `Current' and so forth.

To check if the above statement worked correctly, you just need to run the update statement above and then select from the table again:

```
 select * from Vendor;
```

**Result:**

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| AccountTerms |   ulARAgeing    |
+--------------+-----------------+
|            0 |         Current |
|            1 |         30 Days |
|            2 |         60 Days |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2ee5/2/1)

Comment: And if it has more than 3 records in the table? He would have to write many cases for this?

Comment: @AndrewPaes Nowhere did I read in the question that he has `more than 3 records`. Also, how does it even matter if he has 1..2...or 1000 records with same `AccountTerms`?

Comment: "(i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3) and so on"... "such as: and so on..."

Comment: @AndrewPaes Sorry, that makes no sense. To my understanding, he means that he has values like 0,1,2,3...and so forth in the `AccountTerms` column. And perhaps, I may not be understanding it correctly.

Comment: Thats ok, I think his question is not very clear. I did ask him to make it clear enough.

Comment: Hi Guys, Well this one worked for me the best (mainly because I could understand it) and it did exactly what I needed it to do...

Comment: Hi Andrew, I really am sorry for not explaining it too clearly, its been a hell of a day. Will keep it in mind next time :) Thanks for all your help guys! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome! I am glad that it was easy for you to understand. :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want a simple script to update, then it would be like this:

```
update 
Vendor 
set ulARAgeing = 'Current' 
where AccountTerms = 0;
```

Assuming you want a script where it automatically update the column from a  logic of numeric progression. Then it would be like this:

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (select
            AccountTerms
            ,ulARAgeing
            ,CONCAT((AccountTerms * 30), ' Days') as _ulARAgeing
          from
            Vendor)
UPDATE CTE
SET    ulARAgeing = _ulARAgeing;
```

If by chance the value of "ulARAgeing" come from another table, then the script using "; WITH", you must use a join to get the correct value, instead of using a logic of progression.