# Updating column based on previous value of other column in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to update goal column in this query

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
     id INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
     score int, 
     goal int
)

INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (80)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (86)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (90)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (90)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (90)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (80)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (95)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (95)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (95)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (95)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (95)
INSERT INTO #test(score) VALUES (89)

--- initial goal 5
-- if score is 90 or above for 3 continuous week then goal is 3
-- if score is 95 or above for 5 continuous week then goal is 1
```

Comment: How are you going to determine continuous weeks with no date field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating one column based on the value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102348/updating-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of quick notes:

1. I fixed your sample sql to add a date.
2. I used the `DATEADD` function to easily calculate weeks.
3. Depending on how you wanted your logic, you may have to tweak the `DATEADD` functions in the updates. You weren't 100% clear on if you wanted to be end-exclusive, so I assumed that they were end-**inclusive**.

You should be able to do something similar to this:

```
UPDATE  #Test
SET     Goal = 3
WHERE   Id IN ( SELECT  Id
                FROM    #Test AS t
                OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    COUNT(1) AS 'Number'
                              FROM      #Test AS t2
                              WHERE     t2.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -2, t.Date) AND t.Date AND
                                        t2.Score >= 90
                            ) AS t2
                WHERE   t2.Number >= 3 );

UPDATE  #Test
SET     Goal = 1
WHERE   Id IN ( SELECT  Id
                FROM    #Test AS t
                OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    COUNT(1) AS 'Number'
                              FROM      #Test AS t2
                              WHERE     t2.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -4, t.Date) AND t.Date AND
                                        t2.Score >= 95
                            ) AS t2
                WHERE   t2.Number >= 5 );
```

The hardest part is calculate a "rolling" number. I'm doing this using an `OUTER APPLY`, although it can be done a few different ways. I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622013/calculate-sum-from-moving-4-rows-in-sql) a few years ago, and the solution there was to use a `CROSS APPLY`. So your mileage may vary, and someone else may have a different solution, but this will give you a good idea on how to proceed.

This is the result set that the table ended up with:

[image: Result set]

---

Here's the sql I used to generate the table. Don't forget to drop your temp tables if you plan on using them in your end result!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Test;

DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = '2017-01-01';
CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , Score INT
    , Goal INT
    , Date DATE
    );
INSERT  INTO #Test
        ( Score, Date )
VALUES  ( 80, DATEADD(WEEK, 0, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 86, DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 90, DATEADD(WEEK, 2, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 90, DATEADD(WEEK, 3, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 90, DATEADD(WEEK, 4, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 80, DATEADD(WEEK, 5, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 95, DATEADD(WEEK, 6, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 95, DATEADD(WEEK, 7, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 95, DATEADD(WEEK, 8, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 95, DATEADD(WEEK, 9, @StartDate) )  ,
        ( 95, DATEADD(WEEK, 10, @StartDate) ) ,
        ( 89, DATEADD(WEEK, 11, @StartDate) );

DROP TABLE #Test;
```