# Updating one column based on the value of another column #2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Have a table (settings) with 1000+ rows, and two columns (name, value). I need to update a handful of values, based on the name.

Using [Updating one column based on the value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102348/updating-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column) I get "Invalid Column Name 'AppName' and AppID'".

```
update Test.dbo.Setting
set Value = (CASE 
               WHEN Name = AppName
                 THEN 'Test1'
               WHEN Name = AppID
                 THEN 'Test2'
               END);
```

Why would this work in the other thread, but not in my example? In any case I moved on to wrap the AppName and AppID in single quotes.

```
update Test.dbo.Setting
set Value = (CASE 
               WHEN Name = 'AppName'
                 THEN 'Test1'
               WHEN Name = 'AppID'
                 THEN 'Test2'
               END);
```

Which comes back with "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Value', table 'Test.dbo.Config'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails." Which is true, it doesn't allow NULLs, and my thought is that because there is no ELSE statement it's trying to write NULL to the rest of the 1k+ values.

So lets try it with else..

```
update Test.dbo.Setting
set Value = (CASE 
               WHEN Name = 'AppName'
                 THEN 'Test1'
               WHEN Name = 'AppID'
                 THEN 'Test2'
               ELSE Value
               END);
```

Oops, it works, but also overwrites all Values to what they currently are.. so while it "works" I do not want to touch the other values other than the ones I specify..

Aside from a complete mess of what to try next.. any better ideas on how to optimize?

Thanks.

Comment: first off what do you want to do and is it still a problem? if so please show us your schema and your desired result. .. the Case with the quotes are string comparison while without the quotes are column comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a WHERE clause to update only the rows you want to update:

```
UPDATE Test.dbo.Setting
   SET [Value] = (CASE WHEN [Name] = 'AppName'
                       THEN 'Test1'
                  WHEN [Name] = 'AppID'
                       THEN 'Test2'
                  END)
 WHERE [Name] IN ('AppName', 'AppID')
```

Comment: Oops...I'm just a few second late :). upvoted for same thoughts.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Thinking about it now I did see using WHERE was an option, but I guess I was hoping not to list all of the names twice since there will be about 20 of them. Just seems to make it unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try following to only update the rows you want without overwriting value values:

```
update Test.dbo.Setting
set Value = (CASE 
               WHEN Name = 'AppName'
                 THEN 'Test1'
               WHEN Name = 'AppID'
                 THEN 'Test2'
               END)
WHERE Name IN ('AppName','AppID')
```